# Dhcpd won't start due to selinux

Tags: centos, selinux, dhcpd

have searched tirelessly and can't find an answer to this thats not confusing. I have a clean install of centos 6.2 32bit on a machine I use as a router. with selinux enabled dhcpd refuses to start with the error it can't chown the leases file. I know from digging into the audit log this being caused by selinux and I really hate having to disable selinux but the router is a bit un functional without dhcp server. can someone please tell me how to fix this.

this is the line from audit log that I know is the issue

> type=AVC msg=audit(1560819584.918:174): avc:  denied  { chown } for 
>   pid=2344 comm="dhcpd" capability=0 
>   scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:dhcpd_t:s0
>   tcontext=unconfined_u:system_r:dhcpd_t:s0 tclass=capability

this might as well be some foreign language that i don't know for me

Comment: You need to update your system first.

Comment: what do you mean update system. its an older machine so I have to stick with a system that supports 32bit.

Comment: You need to run `yum update` to install updates, because this apparently hasn't been done since 2012 or so.